# Dynamically create objects in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a library to print graphs in a console as a way to better understand java. I do have my code working but I have to define each object as you see below.  I cant use a for each loop and go through my bar object.  I have a draw bar method in this class that draws the bar line by line. The best way to describe it is, I know its not possible but insert my drawBar code during run time. If you can picture that.

```
ArrayList<Bar> barObjects = new ArrayList<Bar>();

public BarGraph(Bar... bar) {
    // This  constructor method builds the graph object
      for (Bar bars: bar) {
          barObjects.add(bars);
      }
}


// Located in a method
for(int i = 0; i < graphHeight; i++) {
drawBar(placeHolderCount,  10 - barObjects.get(0).getValue(), 0);
drawBar(placeHolderCount,  10 - barObjects.get(1).getValue(), 1);
drawBar(placeHolderCount,  10 - barObjects.get(2).getValue(), 2);
drawBar(placeHolderCount,  10 - barObjects.get(3).getValue(), 3);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm alone, but I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I'm highly confused. At first you're talking about dynamically creating / defining objects, then you talked about injecting a method, I think. Can you clarify / rephrase what you mean?

Comment: I didn't understand the question. As a side note, I suggest to call 'bars' the array and 'bar' the single element of the array. You are currently using those variables with their opposite meaning.

Comment: I understand my question was confusing, La-comadreja answered it correctly. Thank you

Comment: -1? I'm quite afraid to ask questions on here now.. will I ever be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that class Bar contains some type of collection of Bar objects.  You can use a foreach loop.  You just need to explicitly get that collection rather than writing the foreach loop over bar directly.  Write the foreach loop over the collection.

also, write this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < graphHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        drawBar(placeHolderCount,  10 - barObjects.get(j).getValue(), j);
}
```

Comment: Painting graphHeight-times the same thing? there is something that I dont get. Coming from he original question, not from your version

Comment: Perhaps the graph height in the question is 4, therefore the inner for loop is not needed?

Comment: Works great! I thought I tried that and it print to the console wrong for some odd reason. Works now, thank you sir.

Comment: fyi, bar height is how long the bar is vertically in the console. say, 10 lines..